# Building nested form questions based on a 3rd model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I want to build a form for entries, where a couple of contest_questions are predicted by the user.

That means I dynamically wants to fetch the contest_questions related to the tipster-contest and then letting the user register an entry with predictions for each of those questions.

How can I do this? As of now I the fields are not showing up since `<%= f.fields_for :predictions do |prediction| %>`does not execute within the contest_question block and if I change it to `contest_question.fields_for ...`I get a

> undefined method `fields_for' for #

**tipster_contest.rb**

```
class TipsterContest < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bookmaker
    belongs_to :game
    has_many :entries
    has_many :contest_questions

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :history]

    enum status: { "Scheduled" => 0, "Open" => 1, "Closed" => 2, "Graded" => 3 }

    scope :published?, -> { where(published: :true) }
end
```

**entry.rb**

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :tipster_contest
    has_many :predictions

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :predictions
end
```

**contest_question.rb**

```
class ContestQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tipster_contest
    has_many :predictions
end
```

**prediction.rb**

```
class Prediction < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :entry
    has_one :contest_question
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@entry) do |f| %>
  <% @contest.contest_questions.order(name: :asc).each do |contest_question| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :predictions do |prediction| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= prediction.label contest_question.name %>
        <%= prediction.select(:prediction, @contest.teams) %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= prediction.label :wager_amount %>
        <%= prediction.input :wager_amount %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save entry", :class => "btn btn-success" %> <%= link_to 'Back', bets_path, :class => "btn btn-danger" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**And the relevant part of my schema.rb if that would be needed:**

```
create_table "contest_questions", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "tipster_contest_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "result"
    t.integer  "min_wager"
    t.integer  "max_wager"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "entries", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "tipster_contest_id"
    t.integer  "bankroll"
    t.integer  "won"
    t.string   "currency"
    t.boolean  "entry_valid"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "predictions", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "entry_id"
    t.integer  "contest_question_id"
    t.string   "prediction"
    t.integer  "wager_amount"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "tipster_contests", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "bookmaker_id"
    t.integer  "game_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "tournament"
    t.integer  "status",             default: 0
    t.text     "rules"
    t.integer  "prizepool"
    t.string   "currency"
    t.text     "payout_structure"
    t.integer  "tipster_wallet"
    t.string   "teams",              default: [],    array: true
    t.datetime "registration_open"
    t.datetime "registration_close"
    t.boolean  "published",          default: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "logo"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "slug"
  end

  add_index "tipster_contests", ["slug"], name: "index_tipster_contests_on_slug", using: :btree
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out and at least get it working. I don't know if the solution is any good in terms of the rails standard. Anyway here it is:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<% title("#{@contest.name}") %>
<% description("Join #{@contest.name} and use your eSports knowledge to win extra cash or in-game skins for games like CS:GO, Dota 2, etc.") %>

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= form_for(@entry) do |f| %>
  <% if @entry.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@entry.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this entry from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @entry.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.hidden_field 'tipster_contest_id', :value => @contest.id %>

  <div class="t_container">
    <div class="t_row">
      <div class="t_left"><b>Placement</b></div>
      <div class="t_middle"><b>Team</b></div>
      <div class="t_right"><b>Wager Amount</b></div>
    </div>

    <%= f.fields_for :predictions, @predictions do |p| %>
      <div class="t_row">
        <div class="t_left"><%= @entry.contest_questions.order(:name => :asc)[p.index].name %></div>
        <div class="t_middle"><%= p.select :prediction, @contest.teams %></div>
        <div class="t_right"><%= p.text_field :wager_amount, label: "Wager amount" %></div>
        <%= p.hidden_field 'contest_question_id', :value => @entry.contest_questions.order(:name => :asc)[p.index].id %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  </br>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save entry", :class => "btn btn-success" %> <%= link_to 'Back', bets_path, :class => "btn btn-danger" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**entries_controller.rb**

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_entry, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /entries
  # GET /entries.json
  def index
    @entries_open = current_user.entries.includes(:tipster_contest).where(:tipster_contests => {status: 1})
    @entries_closed = current_user.entries.includes(:tipster_contest).where(:tipster_contests => {status: 2})
    @entries_graded = current_user.entries.includes(:tipster_contest).where(:tipster_contests => {status: 3})
    @contests = TipsterContest.where(status: 0..1).includes(:game)
  end

  # GET /entries/1
  # GET /entries/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /entries/new
  def new
    if user_signed_in?
      begin
        @contest = TipsterContest.friendly.find(params[:contest])
        redirect_to tipster_contests_path(@contest), notice: "#{@contest.name} does not accept entries at this point. Registration opens at: #{@contest.registration_open} and closes at: #{@contest.registration_close}." and return true unless @contest.status == "Open"
        @entry = Entry.new(tipster_contest: @contest)
        @predictions = []
        @contest.contest_questions.order(name: :asc).each do |cq|
          @predictions << Prediction.new(entry: @entry.id, contest_question_id: cq.id)
        end
      rescue
        redirect_to tipster_contests_path, notice: 'Could not find a tipster-contest with that ID'
      end
    else
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path, notice: 'You need to sign up to enter the tipster contest!'
    end
  end

  # GET /entries/1/edit
  def edit
    if user_signed_in?
      @contest = @entry.tipster_contest
      @predictions = @entry.predictions
      redirect_to tipster_contests_path, notice: 'This is not your entry to edit' and return true unless @entry.user == current_user
    else
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path, notice: 'You need to sign up to enter or edit a tipster contest entry!'
    end
  end

  # POST /entries
  # POST /entries.json
  def create
    @entry = Entry.new(entry_params)

    @predictions = @entry.predictions

    @contest = @entry.tipster_contest
    @entry.user = current_user
    @entry.won = 0
    @entry.bankroll = @contest.tipster_wallet
    @entry.currency = @contest.currency 

    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.save
        format.html { redirect_to @entry, notice: 'Entry was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @entry }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /entries/1
  # PATCH/PUT /entries/1.json
  def update
    @contest = @entry.tipster_contest
    #@predictions = @entry.predictions

    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.update(entry_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @entry, notice: 'Entry was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @entry }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /entries/1
  # DELETE /entries/1.json
  def destroy
    @entry.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to entries_url, notice: 'Entry was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_entry
      @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def entry_params
      params[:entry].permit(:id, :tipster_contest_id, predictions_attributes: [:prediction, :wager_amount, :contest_question_id, :id])
    end
end
```